# Can someone explain how this is mathematically correct, code in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran77

```
program sum
IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
x = 1
y = 2
z = (x*y)/dtan(0.0D0) 
print *, z
end program sum
```

When I compile this code with [Online Fortran Compiler](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-fortran-online) I get "Infinity". If I write this code in a different language, I get you cannot divide by zero, which makes sense because tan(0) = 0 unless somehow in fortran that 0.0D0 <> 0. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnColeman that's what you got from the question? I am asking how is it mathematically possible...

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortran doesn't directly describe the expected result of the program and the result will depend on the arithmetic model of the processor.

If we assume that IEEE arithmetic is being used then the evaluation of `3d0/0d0` will signal the `ieee_divide_by_zero` flag.  One could also reasonably expect the result of the division to be positive infinity.

What happens when the exception flag is raised depends on the compiler.  A compiler may default to halt when such a flag signals, or it may continue.  A compiler may also have compile-time options to change the response.

Consider the (Fortran 2003) program:

```
  use, intrinsic :: ieee_exceptions
  implicit none
  real(kind(0d0)) x

  x=1

  call ieee_set_halting_mode(ieee_divide_by_zero, .false.)
  print *, x/0

  call ieee_set_halting_mode(ieee_divide_by_zero, .true.)
  print *, x/0
end
```

The first time we try the division we don't halt, possibly printing an infinite value; the second time we do.